# How to stop form auto fill

Tags: forms, input, autocomplete

I would like to stop my login form from auto filling the username and password.
I used autocomplete ="off" but this seem not to help
tried this:

```
    <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="" autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: Which browser(s)? `autocomplete` is not quite working correctly in many browsers; see notes on individual browsers [here](https://caniuse.com/#search=autocomplete).

Comment: I'm using chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just turn off autocomplete for the form completely seeing it's just a login form`<form autocomplete="off"></form>`

Comment: seeing you're also leaving your placeholder empty you might as well take it off entirely